# Is there any debugger for Google Ads-scripts?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I write my first `*.gs` file of Google Ads-script.

Is there any IDE or environment where I can add breakpoints or see the variables state?

I saw only [logger](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/concepts/execution-logs) printing, but that's not efficient to work with.

I have tried @Andrew's reply, but didn't manage:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place dots in next to the line numbers and then click on the little bug icon, like displayed on this image.

[image]

This will open this debug screen:

[image]

Comment: I meant google-ads-script not google-apps-script. Fixed the tags. Where do you run this from?

Comment: Ah, never worked with Google Ads script, but this might still work as they are also .gs files. I always run this by opening a Google Spreadsheet and going to Extra > Script Editor. But you can simply reach it at script.google.com.

Comment: Also remember to click the debug icon, not the run icon (the button that looks like a bug, not the play button)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function.

For example:
MyLogger("test");

```
function MyLogger(s,d=true,w=800,h=400,t=5) {
  const cs=CacheService.getScriptCache();
  const cached=cs.get("Logger");
  const ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM|dd|HH:mm:ss")
  if(cached) {
    var v=Utilities.formatString('%s<br />[%s] - %s',cached,ts,s);   
  }else{
    var v=Utilities.formatString('[%s] - %s',ts,s);
  }
  cs.put("Logger",v,t);
  //allows logging without displaying.
  if(d) {
    const a='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
    const b='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /><br />';
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(b+v+a).setWidth(w).setHeight(h), 'My Logger');
  }
}
```

(To view logs open spreadsheet with your script)

Comment: not sure what's missing: added your method (see original post text).

Comment: `Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.`